# How do I get the count in mongoDB through Spring Boot?

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot

I am new to MongoDB, so please cooperate if I ask something stupid.
please refer the below table

```
status:"Failure"
key:object
   accountID:"AKRRTTY"
```

Can anyone tell me how can I find the counts of status according to the acountID (which is the sub-object of the key)?

The status can be of different types:
such as `Processed`,`Blocked` etc

Comment: Can you show us what have you tried ? It is easy to answer if we see what are the attempts you have made.

Comment: Hi Veeram ...
i have done it like this ...
query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("key.carrier").is(carrierId).andOperator(Criteria.where("status").is("Failure")));

but since This query cannot give me the result for any other status code other then Failure. So, i am looking for any other alternative ...
Please help if you can 

Thanks

Comment: Something like `query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("key.carrier").is(carrierId).and("status").in("Processed","Blocked","Failure")); ` Btw what is your expected output ? Where is the count part in the query ?

Comment: I want count for each one of them for example-:
Process-10
Blocked-10
Failure-12
the count query is -:
carrierLevelStatusTally.setFailed(mongoTemplate.count(query, MessageAuditDoc.class));

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use aggregation to get counts for all status in one go.

You will need to adjust your output pojo to account for aggregation query. Ideally your pojo should contain two fields one for status (_id) and one for count (count).

Something like

```
AggregationOperation match = Aggregation.match(Criteria.where("key.carrier").is(carrierId));
AggregationOperation group = Aggregation.group("status").count().as("count");
AggregationOperation project = Aggregation.project("count").andExclude("_id").andInclude(Fields.from(Fields.field("status", "_id")));


Aggregation agg = Aggregation.newAggregation(match,group,project);

List<YourPojo> results = mongoTemplate.aggregate(agg, colname, YourPojo.class).getMappedResult();
```

Comment: Is this column name is the collection name...?as like TableOnWhichAggregationIsToBePerformed.Class?

Comment: yes that is collection name as in string value not class.

Comment: Hi Veeram,
can you please tell me where i am going wrong as i am getting the status as 
Fetched Result is [DashboardStatusCount [status=null, count=1], DashboardStatusCount [status=null, count=1], DashboardStatusCount [status=null, count=69], DashboardStatusCount [status=null, count=6]]


Status is not coming in the list.

Comment: Updated answer. Please give it a try.

Comment: Thanks for your answer its working now but can you please explain this line-:
AggregationOperation project = Aggregation.project("count").andExclude("_id").andInclude(Fields.from(Fields.field("status", "_id")));\

Comment: Yw. Sure. Group stage outputs document with status value into _id key. Spring maps the keys from mongo result into pojo. So there was no status key the default value null was returned. So to fix it I've added project stage which remaps the status value from _id to status key while keeping other fields.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181521/discussion-between-rishabh-bansal-and-veeram).

Answer (score 0):

You can combine `$match` and `$group` for what you want to achieve. The match operation will filter on `accountID` where the group will combine the results on the status field and count the occurences with an accumulator.

The formatting of the two queries would be like this:

Match query:

```
{'$match': {
   'key.accountID': '<<account_id>>'
   }
}
```

Group query:

```
{'$group': {
   '_id': '$status', 
   'count': {'$sum': 1}
   }
}
```

In java this can be done like this:

```
Arrays.asList(
  match(eq("key.accountID", "test")), 
  group("$status", sum("count", 1L))
)
```

P.S. the java will need the following imports:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import static com.mongodb.client.model.Filters.eq;
import static com.mongodb.client.model.Aggregates.group;
import static com.mongodb.client.model.Aggregates.match;
import static com.mongodb.client.model.Accumulators.sum;
```